# Is it possible to expire data in MongoDB based on multiple properties?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to clean up my MongoDB and I thought about [adding a TTL index to expire documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-after-a-certain-number-of-seconds). But I need different TTLs for my documents, based on a second property.

Here's an example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("525bd2aee4b05e96f1ec7362"),
    "payload"       : "525bd2aee4b05e96f1ec7361",
    "serviceId"     : "525bd2ade4b05e96f1ec735f",
    "status"        : "STARTED",
    "timestamp"     : ISODate("2013-10-14T11:17:01.651Z"),
    "transaction  " : "525bd2aee4b05e96f1ec7360"
}
```

I can set a TTL on property `timestamp`, but I need a different TTL based on `serviceId`. Is this possible in *MongoDB 2.2.x*?

Comment: I removed your second question, because it is 1. a different issue and 2. one which is about administration, and thus would be better placed on https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well, here it is again as a comment: Will MongoDB release space on harddisk when I expire documents and run the compact or repairDatabase commands?

Answer (score 4):

No, a TTL index does not contain any conditional logic except `if field < now - expireAfterSeconds then delete document`.

However, there might be a workaround which could work in your situation: When you have a specific date in the future where you want your document to expire, you can add a field `expireDate` which you set to the date in the future where you want the document to expire. When you then create the index with `expireAfterSeconds` to 0, each document will be deleted when its `expireDate` has passed. This trick allows you to have documents with different TTLs in the same collection.

Comment: Are you sure, a collection can't have more than one TTL index. For example one different index on timestamp field, and another TTL index on serviceIdTimestamp field?

Comment: @cubbuk After reading [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-after-a-certain-number-of-seconds) I am not, so I modified that part of my answer.

Comment: So I guess one solution could be that too then, but your proposal is quite elegant =)

Comment: @cubbuk You could write a second answer to describe multiple TTL indexes as an alternative solution.

Comment: This might be a solution, although I would have to run a job in my application to set the `expireAt` field for existing documents.

Answer (score 0):

While @Philipp's answer is quite useful. There is another way too. You can add a new field to your collection which holds a timestamp for serviceId, and have two TTL indexes seperately one on `timestamp` and the other on `serviceIdTimestamp`.